# Ruby extract filename from url without extension

Tags: ruby, url

I am new to Ruby and would to extract this "14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725" from " "http://www.yahoo.com/14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725.tgz".  Anything after the web link to before the .tgz file

```
url = "http://www.yahoo.com/14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725.tgz"
pattern = url.match( ) # <- regex in here
```

Really appreciate your help in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use parse URL and then using [File.basename](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#basename-method)

```rb
require 'uri'
url = "http://www.yahoo.com/14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725.tgz"

uri = URI.parse(url)

File.basename(uri.path, ".tgz") # => "xy14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725z"
```

if you want to get from any other extension just change `.tgz` to `.*`

Answer (score 2):

```
url = "http://www.yahoo.com/14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725.tgz"
```

```
r = /(?!.*\/)[^.]+/
url[r]
  #=> "14112753-dcfd-4d11-8191-8470a4ad6725"
```

We can write the regular expression in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting.

```
r = /
    (?!    # begin a negative lookahead
      .*   # match zero or more of any characters
      \/   # match a fowward slash
    )      # end negative lookahead
    [^.]+  # match one or more characters other than a period
    /x     # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: would r be '/(?!.*\/)[^.]+/' or '/(?!.*\/)[^.]+/x' ?  I am still trying to understand ... Also, is negative lookahead mean start from backward ?

Comment: The modifier `x` (`/x`) causes all unprotected spaces and comments to be stripped from the regex before it is parsed, causing the expression to be equivalent to `/(?!.*\/)[^.]+/` (which is the same as `/(?!.*\/)[^.]+/x`, `x` being superfluous). `/a b/x` contains an unprotected space; `/[ ]/x` contains a protected space.  No protected spaces are needed here. The negative lookahead causes the match to begin at or after the first character after the last forward slash (i.e., the first character that is not a forward slash that is not followed by a forward slash; in the example, the digit `'1'`).